# Adding Java library into Android project as submodule gives library not found error

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio, android-library

I'm trying to add a **Java library** (Maven project) into my Android project **as a submodule**. I'm using Android Studio.

P.S: For the simplicity of this question, I'll use `samplelib` as my library name.

What I did is:

1- git submodule add `https://www.github.com/samplelib.git`

2- Added the dependencies in my Android project's `settings.gradle` and app level `build.gradle` file

In `build.gradle` (app)

`implementation project(':samplelib')`

In `settings.gradle`

`include ':samplelib'`

But it doesn't work. I'm getting errors like `samplelib not found`

I have tried this for android libraries before and it works but it's not working for Java libraries. Any suggestions?